# How to find given Event datetime is past event or Future event while considering hours aslo

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have Events page, In that displaying past present and future events counts and list. Here I'm facing a issue form QA team.

Example:

```
**Event date** is      : 2022-01-20 08:00:00.000 
**Current datetime** is: 2022-01-20 10:00:00.000
```

now based on above dates , we need to display event as past event because of two hours less than the Current datetime

```
if (planEvents.Count > 0)
{
    switch (statusID)
    {
        case (int)GenericEnum.EventStatus.TodaysEvents:
        events = planEvents.Where(o => o.EventDate.Date == DateTime.Today.Date).Skip(startIndex - 1).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        totalCount = planEvents.Where(o => o.EventDate.Date == DateTime.Today.Date).ToList().Count();
        break;
    }
}
```

I tried above code but it's only returning date matching records but not hours comparison. can any once please help me.

Comment: I tired to compare by using Date but it's giving only date matched records including hours lessthan the current time also. can any one please help me

Comment: I will help you but first clear this query what will be present event? Does present event mean the event falls within the current hour?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should probably use UTC for all times, but that's a different issue. I don't really understand the use case you're after, but you can use the current time and add or subtract time units to create a range start and end. Not tested, but you should have something like this to select from a date range:

```
var start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2); // start from 2 hours ago
var end = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2); // end 2 hours from now
events = planEvents.Where(x => x.EventDate > start && x.EventDate < end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering present events are the one falls within the current hour. Not tested, but it should work

```
if (planEvents.Any()) //Use Any method to improve performance
{
    switch (statusID)
    {
        case (int)GenericEnum.EventStatus.TodaysEvents:
            var todaysEvents = planEvents.Where(o => o.EventDate.Date == DateTime.Today.Date);
            var todaysTotalEvents = todaysEvents.Count();
            var currentHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            var pastEvents = todaysEvents.Where(e=> e.EventDate.Hour < currentHour);
            var presentEvents = todaysEvents.Where(e=> e.EventDate.Hour == currentHour);
            var futureEvents = todaysEvents.Where(e=> e.EventDate.Hour > currentHour);

            break;
    }
}
```